# Compare $R^2$ statistical significance in multivariate multiple regression

Tags: statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis, stata, r-squared, multivariate-regression

I have a multivariate multiple regression model with 3 dependent variables and the same 5 covariates. I used `manova` and `mvreg` in Stata, and I get 3 $R^2$s with my output, one for each Y variable. I would like to compare if the differences between these $R^2$s are statistically significant or not. That is, I want to know if these covariates (all together) explain more variance (statistically) of one of the specific dependent variables.  Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Often, by "multivariate" MR, people mean a single model w/ 3 different Y variables on the left hand side. You say you have an R squared for "each of these models". Do you simply have 3 univariate MR models, or something else? Can you clarify your situation & your question?

Comment: Yes, I have a multivariate with 3 Y variables. I used manova and mvreg in Stata and I get 3 R squared, one for each dependent (Y) variable. I have the same 5 covariates and want to know if these covariates (all together) explain more variance (statistically) of one specific dependent variable. Thank you